# Should I merge two tables that have the same columns but each has a relationship with a different table?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have the following schema:

### SINGLE_CLIENTS:

id  - firstname - lastname - email - address - job

### COMPANY_CLIENTS:

id - name - address - website - email

and I need to add phone numbers to both tables where each entity can have multiple phone numbers each consists of (id - number type - country code - number).

should I use two tables (i.e. SINGLE_CLIENTS_PHONES, COMPANY_CLIENTS_PHONES), just one table (i.e PHONES) or should I store them in a string that resembles an array? and why??

Answer (score 0):

I would keep them in one table. This allows to have only one record for a phone number that is shared by a company and a individual, or use phone number in parts of your app that don't know anything about customers or companies.

Use lookup tables to relate each client type to phone numbers, as this is potentially a many to many relationship.

Comment: but a phone number can only belong to one client (either a single one or a company) so it is a one to many relationship.

Comment: That depends on the implementation, but if it is the case it creates a case for splitting the tables so you van use an fk

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the FOREIGN KEYs.  Get rid of the restriction that "a phone number can only belong to one client (either a single one or a company)".

But, as long as you have two types of clients, you need two Phone tables.  This will allow a "Client" to have multiple phones (fax, mobile, landline, etc).  This is because the client_id needs to be in the Phone table, not the other way around.